# how private static instance variable is accessed in main()

Tags: java

```
public class test
{
    private static int a;
    public static void main(string[] args)
    {
        modify(a);
        system.out.print(a);
    }
    public static void modify(int a)
    {
        a++;
    }
}
```

i want to know how a private static variable is accessed directly in main() method.
although static variables can be accessed directly from static methods but the variable is private and method is main().. pls explain

Comment: @NullUserException: fields are implicitly initialized (to 0, in the case of numerical primitives)

Comment: This works, but all capitals seem to have disappeared from the code. string should be String, test should be Test. The primitive 'a' is initialized to the default value 0.

Comment: Fields are initialized with their default value, if no other value is specified, so this is no problem. Anyway, the `modify()` method increments the local variable of the method and not the field, so it seems pretty useless to call it. It does not return anything and does not modify any value outside the scope of the method. Java has no call by reference.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is static but since it is located in the same class as main method, it can be accessed by the static methods in the class (including main)... and actually also by normal methods in the same class

Comment: Just *don't* pass it as a parameter (see comment by @Colin Hebert)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't bother you that `modif()` can access the attribute `a` ? Then it's the exact same thing with the `main()`.

The only special thing about `main()` is the fact that this method is used as an entry point of your application. This particularity doesn't interfer with the fact that `main()` is static.

---

By the way, your `modif()` method doesn't really access the static `a` field because it's shadowed by the parameter `a`.

Another thing, `a++` won't do anything because you're just modifying the value of the parameter `a` inside a method; `int` is a primitive and is passed by value, so your code won't change the value of `a` outside of the method scope.

I think you wanted something like this :

```
public class test{
    private static int a;
    public static void main(string[] args){
        modify(); //<--- No parameters needed here !
        system.out.print(a);
    }

    public static void modify(){ //<--- No parameters needed here !
        a++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you declare a member variable as private, this means it can only be accessed from methods in the same class. Your `main()` method is actually a static method in the same class, so it can access any private variables.

Answer (score 1):

Since main is in the same class you can access the private variable.

Answer (score 1):

A private member variable is visible to any method of that class, static or not.  There are restrictions on what static methods can do but those are separate from the visibility rules.

Comment: +1 for distinguishing between static/instance and visibility--even if the variable were an instance variable, `main` would be able to access it as `instanceVar.a`

Answer (score 0):

but
public class test
{
    private int a;
    public static void main(string[] args)
    {
             system.out.print(a);
    }

}

you can't access a instance variable 'a' directly in main()... it will show error bcoz it is private...... but how it accesses private static...